# AWS Outbound data transfer charges

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS mentions that at some documentation that there is a minimal outbound data charges within region
http://aws.amazon.com/pricing/

But some documentation says there is no charge. Which one's true?
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 5):

**Data Transfer OUT From us-east-1 Amazon EC2 To**

1. Amazon S3, Amazon Glacier, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon SES, Amazon SQS, or Amazon SimpleDB in the same AWS Region   **$0.00 per GB**
2. Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift or Amazon ElastiCache instances, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, or Elastic Network Interfaces in the same Availability Zone

   - **Using a private IP address $0.00 per GB**
   - **Using a public or Elastic IP address   $0.01 per GB**
3. Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift or Amazon ElastiCache instances, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, or Elastic Network Interfaces in another Availability Zone or peered VPC in the same AWS Region **$0.01 per GB**
4. Another AWS Region or Amazon CloudFront **$0.02 per GB**

**Data Transfer OUT From us-east-1 Amazon EC2 To Internet**

1. First 1 GB / month  $0.00 per GB
2. Up to 10 TB / month $0.12 per GB
3. Next 40 TB / month  $0.09 per GB
4. Next 100 TB / month $0.07 per GB
5. Next 350 TB / month $0.05 per GB

Taken from - https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/